# Angular 2 Login directive and location.createComponent

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, typescript, angular

I implement a login system on my angular app. I found a good resource [here](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.vi6ihoj1r) for that. But there is an error in the custom RouterOutlet directive, which is the following :

```
import { ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader, AttributeMetadata, Directive, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet 
{
    publicRoutes: Array;
    private parentRouter: Router;
    private userService: UserService;

    constructor(
        _elementRef: ElementRef,
        _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
        _parentRouter: Router,
        @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
        userService: UserService
    ) { 
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.publicRoutes = [
            '', 
            'login'
        ];
    }

    activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {

        if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath)) { 
            return super.activate(instruction); 
        }

        this.parentRouter.navigate(['Login']);
    }

    _canActivate(url) {
        return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1 || this.userService.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

And the error is : `TypeError: location.createComponent is not a function`

I read things about it and the problem may be that `_elementRef` is an ElementRef object, and the super method wants a `ViewContainerRef` object. But I'm just beginning to learn angular, and I dont know how to fix this. Beside, Angular2 being still actively developped, things may has changed between the version in the tutorial and mine (which is `2.0.0-rc.1`)

Answer (score 1):

Well writing my hypothesis made me find the solution : It's as simple as importing `ViewContainerRef` instead of ElementRef and get an instance of that in the constructor :

```
constructor(
    _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
    _parentRouter: Router,
    @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
    userService: UserService
) { 
    super(_viewContainerRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.publicRoutes = [
        '', 
        'login'
    ];
}
```

Of course I have no idea what I'm doing, but if it work... Those who knows their stuff and want to add more detail to this are welcome.

Comment: You did the right thing then - if it needs a `ViewContainerRef`, just pass it. I'd rename the variable though for clarification!